# Is Ubuntu 10.04's “Blank screen blinking with white stripes problem” resolved in ubuntu10.10?

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, intel-graphics

In Ubuntu 10.04 the os crashes frequently by displaying "Blank screen blinking with white stripes problem". This problem exists fpr Intel 8xx series chipset users. Now i want to know whether this issue is resolved in ubuntu 10.10 or not?

Comment: In case it matters: due to the many problems of 10.04, Ubuntu released a 10.04.1 version later on. Since 10.04[.1] is LTS (Long Time Support), you may want to give this new version a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the site below, the issue is largely resolved on Maverick but "sadly there is a kernel-bug, which prevents showing the mouse-cursor on 855GM-based systems". For these there is a quick fix dkms package that you can install.

http://glasen-hardt.de/?p=959

Answer (score 1):

There are workarounds for this issue listed on the relevant Launchpad bug reports.

For i845 [Launchpad bug report](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/541492) and [upstream](http://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26345)

For i855: [Launchpad bug report](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/541511) and [upstream](http://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27187)